# Wordpress post sync / publish to production

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, synchronization

I'm using wordpress as a simple backend CMS for a flash site.  Posts are queried and displayed in list format on the frontend.  I want to be able to make post edits or add new posts on my staging server, and have a quick and easy way to publish changes to production without having to do a full mysql db dump / import.  I've looked around for plugins or solutions but haven't found any.  Seems like wordpress needs a "publish to production" option.

The intended workflow is that users can create or edit content as much as they want, then an editor will go through it and approve content.  Once everything looks good on staging, we publish to production.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this thread [at Wordpress might be](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/159738?replies=19) relevant for you as it concerns moving from staging to production and the use of relative and absolute paths, etc.

Answer (score -1):

WordPress does have a preview button that should allow you to see the WP content without actually publishing. If you must see it in the flash site, I think your best bet will be to setup your flash site with XML-PRC.

Comment: I've already built the flash site independent of WP.  It uses AMFPHP to query WP's database.  The preview button doesn't cut it :(

I need a way to sync the staging db to production db.